# How to insert into Relational Tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am teaching myself SQL Server as a bit of a hobby. I have got stuck with inserting data into relational tables, I understand the ideas of relational tables.

I was wondering if anyone could tell me how I can get the identity of the previously inserted row store it as a variable to be used as the FK in the remaining queries.

Here is my TSQL code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[q_insertuser]
@username varchar(50),
@hash varchar(MAX),
@name varchar(50),
@email varchar(MAX),
@address varchar(MAX),
@city varchar(50),
@postcode varchar(50)

AS
--INSERT USERNAME
    INSERT INTO tab_user
    (username)
    VALUES
    (@username)

    --Selects the Userid to be used
DECLARE @UID INT
SET @UID = INT FOR SELECT *
                     FROM tab_user
                     WHERE (userid = SCOPE_IDENTITY())

--INSERT PASSWORD
    INSERT INTO tab_pass
    (userid, hash)
    VALUES
    (@UID ,@hash)

--INSERT Address
    INSERT INTO tab_contact
    (userid,name, email, address, city, postcode)
    VALUES
    (@UID ,@name, @email, @address, @city, @postcode)
--RETURN 0
```

The examples I have seen online seem to be doing it this way but I am getting a typical cryptic error from VS

> (76,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure q_insertuser, Line 19 Invalid column name 'userid'.
>   An error occurred while the batch was being executed.

However the column name userid is present the table that I am querying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

replace this part

```
DECLARE @UID INT
SET @UID = INT FOR SELECT *
                     FROM tab_user
                     WHERE (userid = SCOPE_IDENTITY())
```

with this

```
DECLARE @UID INT
SET @UID =  SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

You can assign the SCOPE_IDENTITY() function directly to a variable, just like getdate() or db_name().

Comment: Another way is to use `OUTPUT` clause.